# Prepopulating checkbox with content from array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a checkbox which calls a function on `ng-click` that inserts into a `checkedItems` array.

How do I prepopulate this checkbox with elements from the `checkedItems` arrray?

Here are the relevent snippets from my setup:

```html
<div ng-repeat="c in c_list">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkSelection(c)"/> {{c}}
</div>
```

```js
$scope.c_list_selected = []
$scope.checkSelection = function (item) {
    if ($scope.c_list_selected.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        $scope.c_list_selected.push(item);
    } else {
        $scope.c_list_selected.splice($scope.c_list_selected.lastIndexOf(item), 1);
    }
}
```

I have tried `ng-bind`, `ng-model` and a few different `ng-checked` expressions. None worked.

Comment: you want to pre-populate DOM with checkbox for each value in checkedItems array?

Comment: Yeah. Basically if I have checkboxed with options `[5,'a','b',6]` and default of `c_list_selected=[5,'b']`; then I want `[5,'b']` values to be selected in the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes bind to booleans. You have to build a mapping (AKA set) of the `checkedItems` array, like this:

```js
$scope.checkedItemsSet = {};
c_list_selected.forEach(function(item) {
  $scope.checkedItemsSet[item] = true; // populate again
});
$scope.$watch(
  'checkedItemsSet',
  function(newV) {
    var k, v;
    angular.copy([], c_list_selected); // empty the list
    for (k in newV) { // populate again for truey attributes of the mapping
      v = newVal[k];
      if (v) {
        c_list_selected.push(parseInt(k)); // attribute names are indeed strings
      }
    }
  },
  true  // check changes by content instead of by object ID.
);
```

Then you bind each checkbox to the corresponding item in the set

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$scope.checkedItemsSet[c]"/>
```